# Skipping registering GPU devices error for Cuda version 11.2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just downloaded cuda 11.3 version and installed cudnn 8.1, added path to both bin and libnvvp. after that i installed tensorflow 2.7(according to tensorflow requirement) but after i run this code to check cuda its giving error

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available(
    cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None
)
```

its giving error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:/Users/Moiz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py:2: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2022-02-13 22:04:16.993299: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-02-13 22:04:17.938394: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2022-02-13 22:04:17.941517: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

Answer (score -2):

hey dude this is was the same error that I got too so I checked it and turns out that some PC dont have the avx for this Try running this command on your terminal or cmd
`pip install tensorflow-gpu` it will reduce the errors which includes gpu which is most on ur case and then it is easy to remove the others

Comment: try this too but facing same error